# Simplifying if(condition): return True to one line return statement changes results in Python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, return, simplify

I do not understand why the two methods written below perform differently. Any insights into why the simplified statement in xyz_there() fails for this test case would be appreciated!

```
str = "abcxyz"

def xyz_there(str):
  for i in range(len(str)):
    return (str[i:i+3] == 'xyz' and str[i-1] != '.')
  return False

def xyz_there2(str):
  for i in range(len(str)):
    if str[i:i+3] == 'xyz' and str[i-1] != '.':
      return True
  return False

print(xyz_there(str))  
print(xyz_there2(str))
```

It has always been my understanding that the return(condition) was the most efficient way to write that expression. I am aware that functions like find() and count() can also be used to solve this problem.

Comment: In the first instance you return from the function whether or not the condition is True or not. So you're always getting the return value for `i = 0`, which is evaluated False

Answer (score 1):

Difference between these two functions is that in second function, `xyz_there2`, the `return True` statement is inside `if`, so it is executed *only if* the condition is true. If it is not true - loop continues to next value of `i`.

However, in first function `xyz_there`, the `return` statement is **not** inside of any `if` statement, so it's executed on first iteration of the loop, thus returning `False` value. And after that the function exits, and loop doesn't get a chance to iterate to next value of `i`.

In other words, `xyz_there` function returns `False` at first loop iteration, when `i==0`. While `xyz_there2` iterates until `i==3`, and returns `True`.

Answer (score 0):

your first function is equivalent to this which is returning Flase :

```
def xyz_there(str):
  return (str[0:3] == 'xyz' and str[-1] != '.')
```

because you are not looping through all the characters in the string , you are just making decision on the first 3 letters of the word and return it